# Change Form submit button's title

Tags: 7, forms

I have a content type called "project" . I want to change the title of the submit button of the edit form.
I wrote a module with the following:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {  
  if ($form_id == 'project-node-form') {  
     $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t('Publish');  
  }  
}
```

I enabled this module but no change of the button title.

please help...thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The form ID of the form alter function is wrong. It should have _ instead of -.

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {  
  if ($form_id == 'project_node_form') {  
     $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t('Publish');  
  }  
}
```